# Controlling BGE properties with python script

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I would like to know how to change the values of properties added using the "AddGameProperty" option in the game logic UI using python code? I want to write code that changes the 'Property' value in an Action Actuator logic block. I attached a screenshot for a bit more clarity:
[image: How do you change the game properties value to control the action actuator using python code??]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to access a property from the current object controller it's :

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
my_property=own['propName']
```

But if you want to access to a property from an other object it's

```
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
my_property=scene.objects['other object']['otherpropName']
```

Comment: When I get the property using scene it shows only the default property, I don't get the current value of the property which changes as the game progresses.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit unclear, but you can use use `own['propName']` to access a property